# How to import msgs/Encoder for python scripts

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm quite new to ROS and trying to read some encoder data from my robot. The robot published its encoder data on a rostopic with type: msgs/Encoder. I would like to make a python script to collect this information.

I have currently done most ROS tutorials including the listerner.py scripts, but my problem is that I cannot find where to import the Encoder type from. and I have not had any luck finding a site with information about the Encoder data type.

Can any of you give me the code line for importing msgs/Encoder, it would be very helpful.

Any link to were I can find information about the topic types would also be most appriciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135281/how-to-import-msgs/encoder-for-python-scripts/) by [toxicburn](https://answers.ros.org/users/12761/toxicburn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally encoder data is published using the [geometry_msgs::Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) type or the [nav_msgs::Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) type.

In your Python node you would use

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
...
sub_encoders = rospy.Subscriber("encoders", Twist, encoder_callback)
```

or

```
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
...
sub_encoders = rospy.Subscriber("encoders", Odometry, encoder_callback)
```

Elsewhere in your code you would create your callback function.

```
def encoder_callback(msg):
    # Do something with encoder data. Only use one of the lines below.
    linear_velocity = msg.linear.x # Twist
    linear_velocity = msg.twist.twist.linear.x # Odometry
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0